# Android Studio MySQL Database Connection throwing Unknown packet type error

Tags: mysql, android-studio, jdbc, database-connection, jtds

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database via Android Studio. I have written the following class to handle the connection.

```
public class ConnectionHelper2 {
    String uname, pass, ip, port, database;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection connectionClass(){
        ip = "sci-project.lboro.ac.uk";
        database = "codc2";
        uname = "codc2";
        pass = HIDDEN;
        port = "3306";

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    
    Connection con = null;

    try{
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        String ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ip+":"+port+";databasename="+database+";User="+uname+";password="+pass+";";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);

        System.out.println("works");

    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e("Errors ", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return con;
}
```

This class is then instantiated in my MainActivity file. However, whenever the program gets to the `con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);` line of code, the program throws the following Exception.

```
I/O Error: Unknown packet type 0x52
```

Any idea why this is? I have the 'jtds-1.3.1.jar' file in my library folder and under my gradle dependencies. I am new to android development and am really stuck on why this isn't working.

Comment: Your connection url seems to be for ms sql server, not for mysql

Comment: try using mysql driver. jtds is for sql server only